# What do CLD and CLR stand for on a delivery certificate ("attestation de remise") when getting a new French passport?

Tags: passports, thailand, terminology, bangkok, french-citizens

I got a new French passport as the [French Embassy in Bangkok](https://goo.gl/maps/cWUww2jgoWiPkdJM8). What do CLD and CLR stand for on a delivery certificate ("attestation de remise") when getting a new French passport?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any official source or reference for this, but it's easy to guess that they are location identifiers, probably the place where you made the application (CLD: Code Lieu de Demande maybe?), and where you will get the passport back (CLR: Code Lieu de Remise?), usually the same.

On yours the code is `THA01`, which probably means `TH` = Thailand, `A` = Embassy (Ambassade), `01` is a sequence number obviously not used for the embassy but probably used for consulates.

Other examples seen on the web use 5-digit numbers which are probably postal codes, INSEE codes, or other similarly derived identifiers, as the first two digits are the number of the *département* which matches the place of delivery.

All in all, it does not seem to affect you in any way. The CLR is "translated" in clear in item (9) on the *attestation de remise*, and is also likewise present on the bio page of your passport under *Autorité*.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "code *de* lieu de..."?

Comment: The _de_ can be safely omitted here IMHO. If you really want to add something, it would actually rather be _du_. But as in any case it's just a wild guess and it possibly means something else entirely...

Comment: If we're just guessing, my guess is that `THA` is the [three-letter code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) for Thailand, as these are the codes used on passports and visas, rather than `TH` + `A`, but I obviously don't know for sure without further evidence.

Comment: @mlc except that Germany's "3-letter" code for passports is, in an inexplicable departure from ISO 3166-1, `D` (or, in the MRZ, arguably `D<<`).  That is a bit of a digression I realize, but good catch on `THA` possibly being all one code.  In that case, `01` could be the embassy, with consulates and other offices, if any, denoted with higher sequence numbers.